# How to call a function inside JSX exported function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-api

This  is part of the code that I have in my home.js file (React App):

```
function pin(){
  var url = "http:myurl"
  axios.get(url)
  .then((res)=>{
    if(res.data){
      var txt = JSON.stringify(res.data)
      var lat = res.latitude
      var lng = res.longitude
      var nivel = res.nivel
      alert(lat)
    }
  })
}

export default function App(){
  const{isLoaded, loadError} = useLoadScript({
    googleMapsApiKey: "mygoogleapikey",
    libraries,
  })

  const [markers, setMarkers] = React.useState([]);
  if(loadError) return "Erro a carregar o mapa"
  if(!isLoaded) return "Carregando"

  return <div>
    <GoogleMap 
    mapContainerStyle={mapContainerStyle} 
    zoom={11} 
    center={center}
    >

    <Marker
      position={{ lat: 40.661096, lng:-7.910098}}
      icon={nivelpin.verde}
    >
    </Marker>

    </GoogleMap>
    
  </div>
}
```

How do I call pin() function inside return? For now I just want to see the alert, to see if what I wrote is correct, but then I want to use it inside the return too, so how do I do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I call a function inside of a .map of arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61922312/how-can-i-call-a-function-inside-of-a-map-of-arrays)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call your pin() from inside the root component (which is the `<div>` in this case). Any code logic needs to be enclosed in braces `{}`

```
return <div>
    { pin() }
    <GoogleMap 
    mapContainerStyle={mapContainerStyle} 
    zoom={11} 
    center={center}
    >

    <Marker
      position={{ lat: 40.661096, lng:-7.910098}}
      icon={nivelpin.verde}
    >
    </Marker>

    </GoogleMap>
    
  </div>
```

Comment: @moredrowsy, why would you call an ajax request from within the template? Can you? Yes. But why? This function would get called on every render, meaning that request is subsequently executed on every render, I don't think that is going to be desired. The payload should be stored in a variable, and the variable should be rendered in a template.

Comment: You're right, the correct way to do it is use hooks, useEffect, for async to change state but he's just asking to execute a code logic. He wasn't asking to update state nor how to handle async lgoic. The topic literally says "How to call a function inside JSX exported function?" If he wants to do async or update state, then he needs to ask another question which is a different topic. And also, it's overkill to overload a beginner with too much technical details.